# Toilet code - 15" from baseboard heater?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain, baseboard

I am remodeling my small bathroom. I know code is for the center of the toliet drain to be 15" from a wall or vanity. There is going to be a baseboard heater on the side of my toliet. Do I have to be 15" from that, or can i go 15" from the wall?

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Most codes require at least 15 inches (measured from the center of the toilet) *from any side wall or obstruction* and not closer than 30 inches center to center to any other sanitary fixture. (The NKBA actually recommends 32 inches.) There should be at least 24 inches of clear space in front of a toilet or bidet.

Sourced from [This Old House](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/ideas/big-help-small-bathrooms), emphasis mine.

If you have the clearance, do 15" from baseboard heating housing. If you don't, can you mount on a different wall, switch to a lower-profile model, or maybe use wall mounted or overhead heat?